# ASP.NET MVC2: How to include js script/resource files compiled into dll?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way in ASP.NET MVC to reference the resource files compiled into dll on the master/view? I'm looking for something similar to the ASP.NET way:

```
Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(PageType), "ResourceName")
```

I'm converting a custom asp server control to MVC html helper. It relies on some js script and I'd hate to tell the client "oh, and just include this file as a script on this page".

ANY kind of help (or even thoughts) would be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have your controller return content that the browser believes is a JavaScript file.  If all of the code to render the JavaScript file is in the controller then it would be rolled up into your app's DLL.

I've done this with CSS having the controller return a view that has a content type of "text/css".  I'm sure the technique could be applied here as well.

Comment: Interesting... So, what I hear in your answer is this:

Comment: (sorry, didn't realize that Enter posts the comment)... So, somehow I could write to the page a "script" tag with some custom url as a source of my js script; then, when the browser requests that url, I could "detect" it, abort the normal response, get the script text from dll and spit it out as a response of "js/text" content type... I think that will work. Great idea, thanks Mayo!